# Looping a Word macro over many list paragraphs causes memory issue

Tags: list, vba, for-loop, ms-word

I'm hitting problem with a reasonably straightforward vba macro for Microsoft Word which is designed to get around some issues we're seeing with list indentation when we create PDFs versions from the Word doc.

The macro basically loops through each list in the document, and for each list paragraph associated with the list, it is setting the list template's bullet and text position to match what's applied at the paragraph level (code needs to be used with Word 2000 so not using list styles).

When dealing with large documents (60+ lists, ~350 list paragraphs), the macro runs through fine first time, but second time dies half way through with a "This method or property is not available because there is a memory or disk problem".

I've gone down the usual route of unsetting any object references used during the loop, so I can't see what might be holding on to the memory.

The code is quite simple and consists of a single procedure, currently stored in ThisDocument:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test2()
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim curList As List, curPar As Paragraph, templ As ListTemplate
    Dim gapSize As Double, level As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Options.Pagination = False

    For i = 1 To Lists.Count
        Set curList = Lists(i)

        For n = 1 To curList.ListParagraphs.Count
            Set curPar = curList.ListParagraphs(n)

            Set templ = curPar.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate
            level = curPar.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber
            gapSize = templ.ListLevels(level).TextPosition - templ.ListLevels(level).NumberPosition

            templ.ListLevels(level).NumberPosition = curPar.LeftIndent - gapSize
            templ.ListLevels(level).TextPosition = curPar.LeftIndent
            templ.ListLevels(level).TabPosition = curPar.TabStops.After(curPar.LeftIndent - gapSize).position

            Set templ = Nothing
            Set curPar = Nothing
        Next n

        UndoClear
        Set curList = Nothing

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Options.Pagination = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Maybe try adding a DoEvents before Next n ?

Comment: I'm seeing something that I suspect is the same issue in Word2010. Essentially when iterating through ListParagraphs if we change the style of one of the paragraphs then ListParagraphs.Count is decremented. This causes Word to crash on evaluating the for statement on last element of the for loop (the last element is now much less than it was when we first started the loop). Steven, did you find any reasonable resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a nasty, dirty solution that gets around the issue somewhat but is really a very poor fix.  Basically, once we have gotten through one complete run of the macro, close and save the document and immediately reopen.  This then allows the macro to be rerun immediately or at any stage because closing the document seems to eventually flush the memory properly.  Obviously this can only be used if the user is happy to save as part of running the macro, but in my case it is

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK and my sugestions will be just ideas to try doing the same another way...
Idea 1: insert a DoEvents somewhere in the innerloop, to facilitate garbage collection.
Idea 2: simplify your code by using FOR EACH constructs:

```
For Each curlist in Lists
    For each curPar in curList.ListParagraphs
       With curPar.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate
          .....
       End With
    Next curPar
Next curList
```

Comment: Hi iDevelop, I've tried both your suggestions, but no joy.  With the doevents, the word app stays responsive for longer but eventually seizes up completely before either hanging completely or giving the memory error.

Comment: @Steven: sorry, I don't think I can help any further. In fact I never programmed Word (but I did a lot of XL and Access). One last try: do you have the latest service pack and updates for your Word version ? Becuase this seems a bit like a bug ! Maybe you could pres Ctrl+Shift+Esc during the macro and see if the memory used by Word grows. But that won't give you the solution of course :-/

Comment: One more try: in Tiago's link, there's an interesting suggestion: do an Undo.Clear every now and then. You might give it a try !

Answer (score 0):

Besides UndoClear, you can also save the document at each loop.

It might heavily impact in your macro performance, though.

There's a similar issue here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/de7a88b4-914f-4895-a88a-659b732e8d87/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Tiago, thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately I've tried that, and it doesn't have any good impacts