# Change bullet spacing based on prior and subsequent lines - Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a macro which can scan through all bullets in a word document and adjust the spacing based on the paragraph lines above and below. The formatting guidelines for our report are:

- The first bullet of a list will have a 3pt space between the prior paragraph and 0pt between between the next bullet (3pt above, 0pt below)
- A bullet between two bullets will have 0pt space above and below
- A bullet at the end of a list will have 0pt space above and 0 pt below

I've tried the following code, but receive an error stating "The requested member of the collection does not exist."

```
Sub BulletAdjust()

Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim negPara As Integer
Dim posPara As Integer
Dim parpos As Integer



'Select Entire document
Selection.WholeStory

With Selection

    For Each oPara In .Paragraphs

    'parapos = position of selected paragraph (index)
    parapos = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.End).Paragraphs.count
    'loop through paragraph lines
    'negpara = line before selected paragraph
    negPara = parapos - 1
    'pospara = line after selected paragraph
    posPara = parapos + 1

       Select Case oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType
            'for bullets w/ bullet above and below
            Case Is = WdListType.wdListBullet And Selection.Paragraphs(negPara).Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet And Selection.Paragraphs(posPara).Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet
                'spacing before and after = 0pt
                oPara.SpaceBefore = 0
                oPara.SpaceAfter = 0
            'for bullets w/ bullet above but none below
            Case Is = WdListType.wdListBullet And Selection.Paragraphs(negPara).Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet And Selection.Paragraphs(posPara).Range.ListFormat.ListType <> WdListType.wdListBullet
                'spacing before = 0pt, after = 3pt
                oPara.SpaceBefore = 0
                oPara.SpaceAfter = 3
            'for bullets w/ no bullet above, bullet below
            Case Is = WdListType.wdListBullet And Selection.Paragraphs(negPara).Range.ListFormat.ListType <> WdListType.wdListBullet And Selection.Paragraphs(posPara).Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet
                'spacing before = 3pt, after = 0pt
                oPara.SpaceBefore = 3
                oPara.SpaceAfter = 0
            'for bullets w/ no bullet above, below
            Case Is = WdListType.wdListBullet And Selection.Paragraphs(negPara).Range.ListFormat.ListType <> WdListType.wdListBullet And Selection.Paragraphs(posPara).Range.ListFormat.ListType <> WdListType.wdListBullet
                oPara.SpaceBefore = 3
                oPara.SpaceAfter = 3
            Case Else
                oPara.SpaceBefore = 6
                oPara.SpaceAfter = 6
        End Select

    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002209/looping-a-word-macro-over-many-list-paragraphs-causes-memory-issue  should give you an idea

Comment: I believe the For ... To was the key; as shown in your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using the following code, if anyone needs something similar:

```
Sub ParagraphCnt()

Dim parano As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph

parano = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.count




For i = 2 To parano
j = i - 1
k = i + 1
Select Case ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.ListFormat.ListType

            'for bullets w/ bullet above and below
            Case Is = WdListType.wdListBullet And ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j).Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet And ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(k).Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet
                'spacing before and after = 0pt
                ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).SpaceBefore = 0
                ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).SpaceAfter = 0
            'for bullets w/ bullet above but none below
            Case Is = WdListType.wdListBullet And ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j).Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet And ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(k).Range.ListFormat.ListType <> WdListType.wdListBullet
                'spacing before = 0pt, after = 3pt
                ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).SpaceBefore = 0
                ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).SpaceAfter = 3
            'for bullets w/ no bullet above, bullet below
            Case Is = WdListType.wdListBullet And ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j).Range.ListFormat.ListType <> WdListType.wdListBullet And ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(k).Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet
                'spacing before = 3pt, after = 0pt
                ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).SpaceBefore = 3
                ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).SpaceAfter = 0
            'for bullets w/ no bullet above, below
            Case Is = WdListType.wdListBullet And ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j).Range.ListFormat.ListType <> WdListType.wdListBullet And ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(k).Range.ListFormat.ListType <> WdListType.wdListBullet
                ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).SpaceBefore = 3
                ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).SpaceAfter = 3
            Case Else

        End Select

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Although this needs some error handling once i = the max # on the count, as k exceeds this by 1. This will work until it hits the last paragraph, at least.

Comment: Your code crashes my friend!  I created a document with just a dotted list of 3 lines. In the second round it issues an "Inem not found" error on `Case Is = WdListType.wdListBullet And ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j).Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet And ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(k).Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet`